# is the following equality about group true

Tags: group-theory

Let $G,G_1,G_2,H$ be groups.

Is the following equality true:

If $G=G_1\cap G_2$ then : $ |H/G|=   |(H/G_1)\times (H/G_2)|$

A specific example is: Is  $|\mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z}| =  |(\mathbb{Z}/m \mathbb{Z})  (\mathbb{Z}/ n \mathbb{Z})|$

Comment: Even once everything has been made to make sense (which takes a bit), the answer is no, as can be seen by considering pretty much any examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two missing assumptions:

(1) Suppose that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are *subgroups* of $H$.
(2) Suppose that $G_1G_2$ is a *subgroup* of $H$.

Let $G=G_1\cap G_2$.  Observe that $G$ is a group.

I am reinterpreting your questions as follows:

Is $|H/G|=|H/(G_1G_2)|$? (Note that you do *not* want the Cartesian product here as the Cartesian product is not a subset.)

Let's consider the finite case, in this case $|H/(G_1G_2)|=\frac{|H|}{|G_1G_2|}$.  Since $|G_1G_2|=\frac{|G_1||G_2|}{|G_1\cap G_2|}$, the original expression equals $\frac{|H|\cdot|G_1\cap G_2|}{|G_1||G_2|}$.  On the other hand, $|H/G|=\frac{|H|}{|G|}=\frac{|H|}{|G_1\cap G_2|}$.  Therefore, the equality that you're looking for holds only if
$$
\frac{|G_1\cap G_2|}{|G_1||G_2|}=\frac{1}{|G_1\cap G_2|}.
$$
In other words, you must have $|G_1\cap G_2|^2=|G_1||G_2|$.  This fails in many cases, for example, when $G_1$ is the trivial group and $G_2$ is not trivial.

Comment: In the finite case you get directly from the assumption that $|G_1\cap G_2| = |G_1G_2|$ which also fails most of the time.